# mongodb query how to calculate with row field? and mongoengine can do this?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I want to select rows where `count < nowtimestamp - update_time`.
In mysql, this is simple:

```
select * from review 
where nowtimestamp - update_time > count;
```

`update_time`, `count` is a table field. So, how does mongodb achive this? I use the mongoengine ORM.

Comment: Show us a sample document - it's unclear what `count`, `nowtimestamp`, and `update_time` are here.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.review.find( { update_time: { $lt: nowtimestamp - count } } )
```

this is the correct syntax for lt in mongodb

just adapt it to your ORM

Comment: that's not work:ReferenceError: count is not defined (shell):1

Comment: `count` is not a variable that you defined previously? or is it a field in your collection?

Comment: it's a field in collection